# New hydraulic disc brake has less stopping power than old rim brake—why?

Tags: brakes, hydraulic-disc-brake, rim-brake

Recently, I upgraded to a [Rockrider 540](https://www.decathlon.co.uk/st-540-mountain-bike-blue-275-id_8500756.html) bicycle. My previous bicycle (a similar but simpler model) had rim brakes, this one has hydraulic disc brakes.

On the new bicycle, the stopping power of the *front* brake is clearly worse than on my old one. However, the rear brake works much better than on the old one.

Does this indicate a fault with the front brake, or does it just need some use before it becomes more effective? How can I fix it and make the brake work better?

Comment: Hi, welcome to bicycles!  How recently did you upgrade?  Disc brakes have a "bedding in" period before they reach full effectiveness; see https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/q/17597/43557

Comment: @DavidW Thank you for pointing that out! I got the bicycle one day ago and I have no prior experience with disc brakes.

Comment: Read up on bedding in, as there are some ways that work better than others.  Pads could also have been contaminated with oil - there is a lot of information here an elsewhere on what should be done in that case

Comment: Thanks to both. This has answered my question.

Comment: Also, when switching from rim to disk brakes, braking feels way softer, because the force is applied at the hub instead of the rim. There's less chance of you tipping over the front, but the brake force is basically the same.

Comment: @Erik "There's less chance of you tipping over the front" I don't see how that could be the case. You go over the bars because you allow your weight to move too far forwards; that doesn't depend on what physical mechanism is stopping the wheel.

Comment: @DavidRicherby that's my observation, if you can't conclude it, so be it.

Comment: @Erik If you've gone over the bars, that's bad breaking technique. If you've gone over the bars enough times to make a statistically meaningful comparison between different brake types, perhaps cycling isn't for you. Perhaps you're instead thinking of the better modulation that disc brakes provide?

Comment: @DavidRicherby if you can ride 10 years through major cities w/o having to do emergency braking, I congratulate you. Otherwise, don't try to tell people if they can do something or not on the internet based on a single statement you likely misinterpreted.

Comment: @Erik I've ridden sixteen years through major cities, thanks. I've emergency braked a number of times. But we were talking about going over the bars; I've never done that, because I know how to use my brakes properly. Furthermore, in all of those 16 years, I've never seen anybody else go over the bars, either.

Comment: As I said, you must be one lucky person.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Disc brakes commonly have issues when:

- they are not bedded in yet. This is required on new bikes or new pads/disc only. The pads and the disc don't have the optimal contact surface established when out of box; [bed-in-process](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/41453/bedding-in-process-for-brakes/41455#41455);
- they get in contact with lubricating substances. There are many ways to clean them, but mainly alcohol should do it; [how-to-clean-disk-brakes](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/54362/how-to-clean-disk-brakes);
- they contain air mixed in with the brake fluid in the circuit. This is hard to detect and requires a full brake bleed. Generally there are low chances this is the case and even lower that both of your brakes have this issue. Checking if the braking power front-back is close to equal should reveal that.

If the disc is clean and there is no air in the circuit, there is no loss of power and that is the true power of your brakes. Tektro 160mm is a low end brake so that wouldn't be a surprise. A workaround is to try a bigger disk if the fork/frame allows.

Comment: I have Tektro 160mm cable operated and they stop on a sixpence, there's no reason they should stop any slower than any other 160mm braking system if set up correctly

Comment: Thanks for the info @DanK, I don't have personal experience with these brakes. However the breaking power differs from one brake to another, depending on the design of lever, the size (even number) of cylinders of the caliper and other less visible manufacturer specific features.